# Is it possible the prevent VS-Code from closing a file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For context; I have a markdown file named `tasks.md` as a pinned tab in which I keep my todo-list. I'm accustomed to hitting `Ctrl + w` to close all unused files, but it also closes this pinned tab.

Is it possible to designate a file as "impossible" to close without changing a vscode setting?

Comment: `ctrl + w` closes one file at a time, so wondering if you do  a `ctrl + w` in your pinned tab `tasks.md` too?

Comment: I'm afraid so, unintentionally

Comment: This is fixed in VSCode 1.50 (Sept. 2020). See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63965809/6309).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sept. 2020, with VSCode 1.50, the [PR 106385](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/106385) will fix that issue.

> Addresses a couple of pain points with pinned tabs:
>
> - Pinned tabs: add a setting to show more context [#98161](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98161)
> - Support pinned tabs when tabs are disabled [#100211](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/100211)
> - Prevent closing the pinned tab when using Ctrl + W [#100738](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/100738)

Regarding the context, [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98161#issuecomment-694707732) from [Benjamin Pasero](https://github.com/bpasero) (who is part of the development team for VSCode) adds:

> After a bit more thought I decided to make `normal` the default option for the `pinnedTabSizing` option because it makes sense to have the default be the normal choice and I feel that forcing a pinned tabs to shrink maybe unexpected for users that see this for the first time.
>
> Setting it to `compact` or `shrink` should be an explicit choice by the user and is then a lot more understandable.

[image: default sizeing]

[image: shrink]

---

With VSCode 1.51 (Oct. 2020):

> ### [More prominent pinned tabs](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/b90c7662cebb51d859506135a03f1ff459f1c743/release-notes/v1_51.md#more-prominent-pinned-tabs)
>
> Pinned tabs will now always show their pin icon, even while inactive, to make it easier to identify them.
> If an editor is both pinned and contains unsaved changes, the icon reflects both states.
>
> [image: Inactive pinned tabs -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/b90c7662cebb51d859506135a03f1ff459f1c743/release-notes/images/1_51/pinned-tabs.png]

---

And make sure to use VSCode 1.82 (Aug. 2023): [issue 115734](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/115734) reported "Add setting to prevent closing the pinned tab when using middle click"

> A pinned tab cannot be closed with ctrl + w, but it can be closed with the mouse (middle click).

[PR 188592](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/188592) adds the setting:

#### `workbench.editor.preventPinnedEditorClose`:

- `always`: Always prevent closing the pinned editor when using mouse middle click or keyboard.
- `onlyKeyboard`: Prevent closing the pinned editor when using the keyboard.
- `onlyMouse`: Prevent closing the pinned editor when using mouse middle click.
- `never`: Never prevent closing a pinned editor.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing settings: Keyboard Binding Logic `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` it's not possible currently. Upvote this [Prevent closing the pinned tab when using Ctrl + W](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/100738) feature request in the VS Code Issue tracker. It'll get to VS Code Dev's backlog if it gets more than [20 upvotes in 60 days](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/100738#issuecomment-647481003) (August 21, 2020).